# how to update data without change existing data c# ms access

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hi guys when I want to update without changing old data I get this error

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'data.[Phone Number]+ ' ' +0770444 +'.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\db\\it.accdb");
con.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE data SET data.[Phone Number] = data.[Phone Number]+ ' ' +"+textBox23.Text+" +  WHERE data.([ID]) = " + textBox15.Text + " ";
cmd.Connection = con;

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt;
dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

MessageBox.Show("Data Updated Successfully");
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using Command Parameters and you will avoid problems like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE data SET [Phone Number] = [Phone Number] + ' ' + @NewPhoneNumber WHERE ID = @ID ";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox15.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPhoneNumber", textBox23.Text);

cmd.Connection = con;
```

Also this will protect you from Sql Injection. Be aware you should provide proper naming of your controls(textboxes), this names means nothing for other programmers. Write your columns together `PhoneNumber` it is annoying to escape them all the time, you are creating more work for yourself for no reason.

Other points wrap your OleDbConnection and OleDbDataAdapter in using blocks

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\db\\it.accdb"))
{
    con.Open();

    //... stuff

    DataTable dt;
    using(OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
         //stuff relate to db adapter
    }

}
```

Using is representing try/catch/finally with calling `Dispose()` in finally block. This will protect if your code have an exception your connection will be closed. In your current format this is not happening. `OleDbDataAdapter` is using unmanaged resources so it should be `Dispose()` too.

Comment: @babanjamal did you provide proper value in textBox23.Text ? Is the ID correct ?

Comment: ID is Auto number so I changed it to integer the code work fine but nod add the number to existing number

Comment: can I use this           "UPDATE data SET [Phone Number] = [Phone Number] + '" + textBox23.Text + "'  WHERE [ID] = '" + textBox15.Text + "'  ";

Comment: hi Bro yours worked with me but when I go to my database or search for it I can not find the new number

Comment: con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE data SET [Phone Number] = [Phone Number]+@NewPhoneNumber WHERE ID = @ID ";
            cmd.Connection = con;
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox15.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPhoneNumber", textBox23.Text);
          OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
              DataTable dt;
              dt = new DataTable();
              da.Fill(dt);
              dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();

Answer (score 0):

Your command seems to be wrong it should be

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE data SET data.[Phone Number] = " + "'" + data.[Phone Number] + textBox23.Text + "' WHERE data.([ID]) = " + textBox15.Text;
```

Whereas it is always recommended that we should use the Parameterized Query instead of string concat.

Comment: can I use this "UPDATE data SET [Phone Number] = [Phone Number] + '" + textBox23.Text + "'  WHERE [ID] = '" + textBox15.Text + "'  ";

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys I resolved it by this

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE data  SET [Phone Number] = [Phone Number]+\n'" + textBox3.Text + "' WHERE ID = " + textBox15.Text + " ";
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

MessageBox.Show("New Number Inserted Successfully to ID " + textBox15.Text);

con.Open();
```